# How Do I Remove A DynamoDB Property With AWS Amplify V5?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I would like to use an update mutation, to make property is removed from the item on DynamoDB.

`published: PUBLISHED` is set in my schema, with `enum PUBLISHED { YES }` as the `enum`. I am using this to benefit from [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html).

What can I do to ensure I remove the `published` property from the DynamoDB item?

**My Code:**

```
const updateJobListing = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdateJobListing($input: UpdateJobListingInput!, $condition: ModelJobListingConditionInput) {
    updateJobListing(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      published
    }
  }
`;

  await API.graphql({
    query: updateJobListing,
    variables: {
      input: {
        published: null,
      },
    },
    authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
  });
```

**My Error:**

```
data : null
errorInfo: null
errorType: "Unauthorized"
locations: [{…}]
message: "Unauthorized on [published]"
path: ['updateJobListing']
```

Comment: What role do you have for the unauthorised Cognito user pool?

Comment: I have set the role to IAM. I believe the issue has nothing to do with authorisation, as I can set the value to any string after removing the `enum`. It just cannot be `null`.